# When does $\varphi(n) = n/6$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble showing this. I was able to show when $\varphi(n) = n/2$, and $\varphi(n)  = n/3$, but I don't know when $\varphi(n)  = n/6$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=\prod_{p|n} \frac{p-1}{p}$ you need to find all $n$ so that

$$\prod_{p|n} \frac{p-1}{p} =\frac{1}{6} $$

Let $p_1< ..<p_k$ be all primes dividing $n$. Then

$$6(p_1-1)(p_2-1)...(p_k-1)=p_1p_2...p_k \,.$$

Thus

$$p_k | 6(p_1-1)(p_2-1)...(p_k-1) \,.$$

Since $p_k$ is prime, and larger than $p_i-1$ it follows that $p_k | 6$. Thus $p_k=2$ or $p_k=3$.

This shows that $n=2^k3^l$.

It is easy to check that no such number is a solution, note that you have to check three cases $k=0$ or $l=0$ or $k\neq0,l\neq 0$.

Comment: so you're saying that there aren't any phi(n) = n/6?

Comment: @David Yup, unless I did a mistake :)